# How can I make Perl print first ten lines of a string?

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to show the first ten lines of a large string (first 10 lines of a paragraph). I've tried to use:

```
 $lines = head-10 $string
```

I saw some examples that use `while` loops but my script can't facilicate that, I need it to be a variable.

Next I tried to use:

```
 $string = perl -pe'$.>10&&last'
```

which gave me the desired result by typing

```
String= "$(string | head -n10)"
```

Comment: Why can't you use a loop in perl? It's a basic tool. In this context, what do you mean by "I need it to be a variable" as one does not preclude the other?  I've been doing perl for 20+, but I'm having some difficulty understanding your intent, desire, and problem constraints. Otherwise, an answer would be quite simple. Several different methods, in fact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do this in the code, split the paragraph into a list, use an array slice to get the first 10 elements and join them back together again by adding the newlines back.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my $string = "line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12";

#  turn the lines into a list by splitting on newline
my @lines = split "\n", $string;

#  take an array slice of the first 10 list items and join them into a string
#  delimited by a newline
my $first_ten = join "\n", @lines[0 .. 9];

#  print your 10 lines
print $first_ten;
```

Comment: @collapsar's answer is more efficient since he's just reading the 10 first lines of the variable, although syntactically more complex since he's using the concept of linking a scalar variable to a file handler. Here instead, you are duplicating the `$string` content in a splitted array just to discard it afterwards.

Comment: Efficient but hard to read and buggy to maintain.  I'd still much rather put this into implementation and take the clarity of action.

Comment: Well, until you have a files that's several gigabytes you'd say that.

Answer (score 2):

Perl allows you to open a filehandle on a string. You can then use filehandle idioms to "read" the string.

```
my $string = <<"HERE";
This is the first line
This is the second line
3rd
4th
5th
6th
seventh
one plus seventh
eighth
tenth minus one
tenth
should not go this far
way to far
okay stop now, srsly
This is the last line
HERE


open my $fh, '<:utf8', \ $string or die;
while( 0 .. 10 ) {
    print { STDOUT } scalar <$fh>;
    }
close $fh;
```

In this example, instead of a filename I give `open` a reference to a scalar. Now I have a filehandle on that scalar.

In the `while`, I use the flip-flop operator. It looks like the range operator, but in boolean context it's different. It is true when the first condition is true, and stays true until the second condition is true. That is, it turns on, stays on, then turns off.

When you use number literals with the flip flop, it looks at the line number for the currently read filehandle (in this case $fh). So, we turn it on when the line number is 0 and turn it off when the line number is 10. That means that the loop doesn't execute when the line number is 10 because the condition is now false. But, that's okay because that's actually line 11.

Or, you can do that with a counting `for` loop:

```
open my $fh, '<:utf8', \ $string or die;
for( my $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
    print { STDOUT } scalar <$fh>;
    }
close $fh;
```

In both examples I use `scalar <$fh>` to get the next line because I used it inline with the `print`, a list context operator. I don't want all the lines. I surround the output handle in braces to set it apart from the rest of what's going on.

But, you're asking about it being in a bash script it looks like. Anything you can do in a "normal" perl program you can do in the argument to `-e`:

```
perl -e 'open my $fh, q(<:utf8), \ $ARGV[0] or die;
    for( my $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
        print { STDOUT } scalar <$fh>;
        }
    close $fh;' string_arg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution between `>>>> START...` and `<<<< END...` comments (The remainder is wrapper code to turn it into a standalone script for demo/testing purposes). After the solution section, `$s_start` will contain the first 10 lines of `$s_raw`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use warnings;

my (
      $n_lines
    , $s_raw
    , $s_start
    , $s_thisline
);

{ local $/ = undef; $s_raw = <DATA>; }

#>>>> START of core code section
$n_lines = 0;
open $fh_raw, "<", \$s_raw;
while ( ($n_lines < 10) && ($s_thisline = <$fh_raw>) ) {
    $s_start .= $s_thisline;
    $n_lines++;
}
close $fh_raw;
#<<<< END of core code section

print $s_start;
exit(0);

__DATA__
This is a test
with lots of lines
and
a bit
repetitive in nature
however
it 
serves the purpose
of demonstrating
the
code above
...(arbitrarily more stuff) ...
```

Comment: downvoter, pls comment to allow for an improvement of the answer or give a reason to remove it altogether

Comment: Why do you put all the data content in the `$s_raw` scalar (with `{ local $/ = undef; $s_raw = <DATA>; }`) for after using it with a filehandler? What a crazy idea! You can obtain the same result reading the data content line by line writing: `while (<DATA> && $n_lines < 10) {`

Comment: @Casimir, that's for emulating the context of the question: *Im trying to show the first ten lines of a large string*  - Unfortunately it seems this has not been understood...  this answer is far better than the one accepted.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The wrapper code is indeed for setup purposes of the demo script only and does not belong to the actual solution between 'start'/'end' comments. Thanks for pointing out that this remains unclear.

Comment: Perl allows trailing commas so you don't have to use the wacky SQL idiom with leading commas :)